# How to EnsureUser with AD group in REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I am trying to add AD group to SharePoint site in REST using EnsureUser but I kept getting error message "*The specified user c:0+.w|S-1-5-21-1814438218-152777602-930774774-762833 could not be found*". Can someone please tell me what the correct format is for the logonName string? AD is on prem and we are using SP Online. Below is the code:

```
        string digest = formDigest == "" ? GetRequestDigest() : formDigest;
        string logonNameStr = WebUtility.HtmlEncode("c:0+.w|") + "S-1-5-21-1814438218-152777602-930774774-762833"; <== This seems to be incorrect
        string ensureUserUrl = _siteUrl + "_api/web/EnsureUser"; 
        
        using (var handler = GetHttpClientHandler(_siteUrl))
        {
            using (HttpClient client = GetHttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);
                var payload = new { logonName = logonNameStr };
                string jsonBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload);
                using (StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonBody))
                {
                    content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(ensureUserUrl, content).Result;
                    string jsonStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) //if adding user failed
                    {
                        throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed to add AD group {0} to SharePoint site: {1}", groupName, jsonStr));
                    }
                }               

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from the MS Engineer. The LogonNameStr just have to be the name of the AD Group, no domain, no SID. And that works successfully.